# How to make Tuple Type to conform a protocol in swift?

Tags: swift, generics

```
func foo<T:Collection>(val: T) where T.Element: Codable {}

foo(val: ["hello", "hi"]) // ok

// Type '(key: String, value: String)' cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
foo(val: ["hello": "hi"]) // error
```

I know dictionary's associated type, `Element`, is `(key: Key, value: Value)`.

But I want to know how to make the `Element` of tuple of `(key: String, value: String)` to conform `Codable`?

Comment: Did you write `foo` yourself or do you have no control over it? Also, can you show what `foo` does? This will tell us why `T.Element` needs to be `Codable`.

Comment: yes, no control, it is just an example when i tried writing to support collection whose `Element` is tuple of `(key: Key, value: Value)`. which i want to make this `Element` to conform `Codable`

Comment: Can you show what `foo` does? Ideally, show its implementation. It might not make sense to pass a dictionary in there.

Comment: And to answer your question: it is not possible to conform non-nominal types (such as tuples) to protocols.