# Conform element of dictionary to CustomStringConvertible in swift

Tags: swift

I want make a conformance to elements of a dictionary for CustomStringConvertible, I tried this code, but it has error of:

> Cannot find type 'Key' in scope

```
extension Dictionary<Key, Any>.Element: CustomStringConvertible where Key: Hashable & CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "(" + String(describing: self.key) + ", " + String(describing: self.value) + ")"
    }
}
```

use case:

```
func test() {
    
    let dictionary: Dictionary<String, String> = ["1": "a", "2": "b", "3": "c"]
    
    dictionary.forEach { item in
        
        print(item.description)

    }
    
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary<Key, Any>.Element` is just a tuple type, and tuple types are non-nominal types. They cannot conform to protocols, nor can you make extensions out of them, so no this is not possible.

Comment: You would need to override `description` and loop over the key/values inside the computed property, like `self.reduce("") { $0 + ("(" + String(describing: $1.key) + ", " + String(describing: $1.value) + ")") }`

Comment: @Sweeper: Yes, You missing something, the OP asked literally about conformation to CustomStringConvertible. You are not the only one knows about printing elements of a sequence.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63949405/how-to-make-tuple-type-to-conform-a-protocol-in-swift

Comment: I like this question, since it challenges some of the Swift's outstanding issues with ambiguity between type vs namespace. But as said above, I don't think there's a more elegant solution than making Dictionary conform to CustomStringConvertible, and looping over its elements. Other possibilities I see are: convert your dictionary to JSON (kind of ugly), or define your own type similar to `Element` outside of dictionary, make it conform to CustomStringConvertible, and then have an extension for dictionary to accept your custom element  (also not greate, if even possible - didn't try)

Comment: @KirilS.: It is very usual that I used tuple in my projects and in some were I should conform it to a protocol, in that case I must make a CustomType for solving the issue, but if I do the same thing here for solving the issue, that would be very expensive approach, and that would be an array or set of customTypes, right? It would not be a dic anymore!

Comment: The problem is not in typealias, the problem is that you want to use a Dictionary as a namespace, check this dicussion for example: https://forums.swift.org/t/nesting-a-type-within-an-extension-to-a-generic-type-requires-indicating-the-parent-s-generic-type-when-used/36582/6 (in that discussion they have an even simpler case, where struct within dictionary doesn't need any generics...)